# Changing the case of a string with awk

Tags: regex, unix, awk

I'm an awk newbie, so please bear with me.

The goal is to change the case of a string such that the first letter of every word is uppercase and the remaining letters are lowercase. (To keep the example simple, "word" is defined here as strictly alphabetic characters; all others are considered separators.)

I learned a nice way to make the first letter of every word uppercase from another post on this website using the following awk command:

`echo 'abce efgh ijkl mnop' | awk '{for (i=1;i <= NF;i++) {sub(".",substr(toupper($i),1,1),$i)} print}'`  -->  Abcd Efgh Ijkl Mnop

Making the remaining letters lowercase is easily accomplished by preceding the awk command with a tr command:

`echo 'aBcD EfGh ijkl MNOP' | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | awk '{for (i=1;i <= NF;i++) {sub(".",substr(toupper($i),1,1),$i)} print}'`  -->  Abcd Efgh Ijkl Mnop

However, in the interest of learning more about awk, I wanted to change the case of all but the first letter to lowercase with a similar awk construct. I used the regular expression `\B[A-Za-z]+` to match all letters of a word but the first, and the awk command `substr(tolower($i),2)` to provide those same letters in lowercase, as follows:

`echo 'ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP' | awk '{for (i=1;i <= NF;i++) {sub("\B[A-Za-z]+",substr(tolower($i),2),$i)} print}'`  -->  Abcd EFGH IJKL MNOP

Notice that the first word converted properly, but the remaining words are left unchanged. I would be very grateful for an explanation of why the remaining words did not convert properly and how to get them to do so.

Comment: you can find the solution [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/caplitalizechange-to-uppercase-first.html)

Comment: Although I was trying to solve the problem with `awk`, thank you for the link to a nice `perl` solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that `\B` (zero-width non-word boundary) only seems to match at the beginning of the line, so `$1` works but `$2` and following fields do not match the regex, so they are not substituted and remain uppercase. Not sure why `\B` doesn't match except for the first field... B should match anywhere within any word:

```
echo 'ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP' | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { print match($i, /\B/); }}'
2   # \B matches ABCD at 2nd character as expected
0   # no match for EFGH
0   # no match for IJKL
0   # no match for MNOP
```

Anyway to achieve your result (capitalize only the first character of the line), you can operate on `$0` (the whole line) instead of using a `for` loop:

```
echo 'ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP' | awk '{print toupper(substr($0,1,1)) tolower(substr($0,2)) }'
```

Or if you still wanted to capitalize each word separately but with `awk` only:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) tolower(substr($i,2)); } print }'
```

Comment: Thank you for showing that `\B` unfortunately only operates at the beginning of the line. With your suggested construct without the `for` loop, the first word changed case as desired but the remainder became lowercase: Abcd efgh ijkl mnop

Comment: @scolfax, yes at first I interpreted your request "I wanted to change the case of all but the first letter to lowercase" as all letters of the *line*. But I also provided a second construct below, in case you wanted to uppercase the first letter of each *word* instead.

Comment: That did it! Simpler than using the `sub` command. Thank you very much. I've been a `grep` and `sed` person for some time, but it's finally time to dive into `awk`!

Answer (score 4):

When matching regex using the `sub()` function or others (like `gsub()` etc), it's best used in the following form:

```
sub(/regex/, replacement, target)
```

This is different from what you have:

```
sub("regex", replacement, target)
```

So your command becomes:

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/\B\w+/, substr(tolower($i),2), $i) }1'
```

Results:

```
Abcd Efgh Ijkl Mnop
```

This article on [String Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) maybe worth a read. HTH.

---

I should say that there are easier ways to accomplish what you want, for example using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -r 's/\B\w+/\L&/g'
```

Comment: The link you provided describes nicely why regex literals /.../ are much preferred over strings "...", and I will make that change henceforth. However, for some reason, I got the same result as before, with only the first word converting case: `echo 'ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP' | awk '{for (i=1;i <= NF;i++) sub(/\B[A-Za-z]+/, substr(tolower($i),2),$i)}1'`  -->  Abcd EFGH IJKL MNOP. I wonder if this is due to an `awk` version difference (mine is OS X, which by the way doesn't support `\L` in the `sed` command, unfortunately).

Answer (score 3):

My solution will be to get the first part of the `sub` with a first `substr` insted of your regex :

```
echo 'ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP' | awk '{for (i=1 ; i <= NF ; i++) {sub(substr($i,2),tolower(substr($i,2)),$i)} print }'
Abcd Efgh Ijkl Mnop
```

Comment: Using `substr($i,1)` itself as the regex is very creative. At first I thought I could run into problems if that sequence of characters was repeated later in the same word, but I believe `sub` matches only the first occurrence, so your solution should work fine. Thank you for this nice solution.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `substr($i,2)`. And cancel my comment about a second occurrence, since ($i,2) consists of the entire word from the second character on.

Comment: Actually, this construct does run into a problem if the 2nd-through-last characters match the 1st-through-(last - 1) characters: `echo 'AAAA' | awk '{for (i=1 ; i <= NF ; i++) {sub(substr($i,2),tolower(substr($i,2)),$i)} print }'`  -->  aaaA

Comment: Effectively i thought about repeted sequence but not about the problem you pointed, i'll probably look about an other/improved solution. But you choose an answer so probably not immediatly...

Comment: You can sub all the $i to be good, but that's end with an equivalent of the accepted solution : `echo 'ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP AAAA' | awk '{for (i=1 ; i <= NF ; i++) {sub($i,substr($i,1,1)tolower(substr($i,2)),$i)} print }'
Abcd Efgh Ijkl Mnop Aaaa`

Comment: Thank you. That corrects the problem. (Being somewhat inexperienced, I chose an answer too quickly and learned from this to wait until everyone has had a chance to share their thoughts.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add another \ character before \B

```
 echo 'ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP' | awk '{for (i=1;i <= NF;i++)
 {sub("\\B[A-Za-z]+",substr(tolower($i),2),$i)} print}'
```

With just \B awk gave me this warning:

> awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\B' treated as plain`B'

Comment: I understand the use of the second \ character in the regex string: to make sure it is interpreted as `\B` rather than an escaped `B`. However, for some reason, my version of `awk` (OS X) seemed to interpret it as `\B` anyway, and adding the second \ character didn't change the result. But thanks for that good reminder.