# How to apply awk command to a specific field only

Tags: bash, awk

I have found a partial solution to my issue in: "[Changing the case of a string with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139672/changing-the-case-of-a-string-with-awk)", the command posted by @AndersJohansson is:

```
echo 'ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP QRST UVWX' | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) { $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) tolower(substr($i,2)); } print }'
```

Which ends printing **Abcd Efgh Ijkl Mnop Qrst Uvwx**, as expected.
But, in my case I have the data separated by fields, like: `ABCD EFGH; IJKL MNOP; QRST UVWX` and I need to apply the command to the 3r (last) field only (actually in my data there are 9 fields, but for simplicity I put just 3).

Expected output: `ABCD EFGH; IJKL MNOP; Qrst Uvwx`

Inside Stackoverflow there is a good number of related questions, even one of my own ([How to sort inside a cell captured by awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70656851/how-to-sort-inside-a-cell-captured-by-awk)) , I went one by one trying to adapt them to my case without success, obviously I have not enough knowledge about awk as to overcome with the solution, so I will really appreciate any help on solving this... thanks.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Why did you tag this with javascript? Why didn't you tag it with awk?

Comment: I did tagged awk, I don't know what went wrong on the way that it was changed to javascript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```sh
echo "ABCD EFGH; IJKL MNOP; QRST UVWX" |
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "; "}
    {
        s = "";
        n = split($NF,w,/ /);
        for(i=1; i<=n; ++i)
            s = s " " toupper(substr(w[i],1,1)) tolower(substr(w[i],2))
    }
    {$NF = substr(s,2)}
    1
'
```

output:

```
ABCD EFGH; IJKL MNOP; Qrst Uvwx
```

###### Explanations:

- setting `FS` to `": "` will make `awk` split the line in fields separated by `": "`; in the current case, you'll get three fields.
- `$NF` references the last field, which is then *manually* [split](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13) on each space character.
- The for loop does the upper/lower transformations and store them in a string variable.
- Then the last field is updated and the whole line is printed; `OFS` has to be set to the same value as `FS`, or else the `"; "` will be converted to `" "` when printing the line.

Comment: Thanks, yours solved it, I have tried this `BEGIN` set, but I really don't know how it works, so i just did a mess with it...

Comment: Could you explain why this works? Otherwise it's just magic...

Comment: OK, I added some explanations in the answer

Comment: Thanks! You got my upvote then